# How to center-align text in Scintilla?

Tags: scintilla

In my application I have a custom control that implements syntax highlighting via the scintilla.dll.

[There are all sorts of codes](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#StyleDefinition) for setting the style of the text in the control.

However, I've searched and searched and can't figure out how to center-align text in the control.

What's the scintilla code for center-aligning a text style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "center-align" command in scintilla.

Here is what to do, however, to center the text:

1. Fetch the text from the control
2. Know what style is being used
3. Use `TEXTWIDTH` (`2276`) to figure the width of the text using that style
4. Use controlwidth /2 - textwidth /2 to figure the location of the left margin
5. Use `SETMARGINLEFT`  (`2155`) to move the left margin

Note that the default style is `32`.

You'll have to figure your code to update the location every time, however, maybe via some callback function.

In Autohotkey, it could look like this:

```
guicontrolget, editor
guicontrolget, editor, pos
textwidth := hwndeditor.2276(32,editor)
setplace := (editorW /2) - textwidth /2
hpeditor.2155(0,setplace)
```